# how to make items in a listview from SQLite clickable by kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new in kotlin and I want to know How can I make the `listview` that displays data from the database clickable and I want the  items to move me to specific `activity` but carry different data each time depending on the item's data via Kotlin ,I try this but it is not working and I set position manually.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener { parent:AdapterView<*>, view:View, position:Int, id:Long ->
            if (position==0){
                var intent: Intent = Intent(this, vacc_show::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }

            if (position==1){
                var intent: Intent = Intent(this, vacc_show::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            if (position==2){
                var intent: Intent = Intent(this, vacc_show::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            if (position==3){
                var intent: Intent = Intent(this, vacc_show::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            if (position==4){
                var intent: Intent = Intent(this, vacc_show::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing data to the `Intent` object. Using position you can get data and put that data into intent object. you can put any other info also into intent.
Do it like :

```
val data = myList.get(position) // Keep in mind your data must be parcelable type
intent.putExtra("data_atposition",data)
intent.putExtra("position_key",position)  // It is just a (key,value) pair
```

Your final code snippet should be like following :

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener { parent:AdapterView<*>, view:View, position:Int, id:Long ->
            
                var intent: Intent = Intent(this, vacc_show::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("position_key",position)
                startActivity(intent)
            

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but keep in mind that the user will enter the data and we don't know how many elements he will enter, is there a way to make all the elements likely to enter the user clickable

Comment: setOnItemClickListener will enable all items clickable.
Check my updated answer. Am i getting your issue ?